# Google Play store Cross App Scripting Error

Tags: android, android-security

Every time I upload my app update to google playstore , I am sent the message: **Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to cross-app scripting**. However, I am not using any Webview in my application and i have effected all the changes google recommended. I contacted Google so many times to direct me to the source of the error, but to no avail. Has anyone experienced this error before? My app updates are all being rejected and I don't know where the error is.

Comment: I have written a solution, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Go to the android Manifest, and if the web activity has the `android:exported="true"`, Change it to `android:exported="false"`

Go to the manifest, and add the following lines in the Webview activity

```
<meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
android:value="true" />
```

Comment: I have already added android:exported="false" as well as EnableSafeBrowsing but the error still persists. Moreover, the thing is , I do not have any Webview activity in my project.